How do I properly retrieve data from the video and image view for processing in java using ffmpegKit
The rest of the code is highlighted in the comments below. The errors I keep on encounting are: "Cannot resolve method MergeVideoClips","Cannot resolve Method AddAudio()",


//I want to create a java activity in android studio studio java. I want to create an activity //that         
 //will allow the app to edit photos and videos as done in professional applications // like Premier       
 //Pro and Photoshop.



   package com.example.self_editor;

    import android.Manifest;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.graphics.ColorMatrix;
    import android.graphics.ColorMatrixColorFilter;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.MediaController;
    import android.widget.VideoView;
    import android.widget.Toast;`

    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
    import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

    import org.videolan.libvlc.LibVLC;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.FFmpegKit;
    import android.net.Uri;

    public class VideoEditorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
    private static final int PICK_VIDEO_REQUEST = 2;
    private static final  int  RETURN_CODE_SUCCESS = 0 ;

    private VideoView videoView;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private Bitmap selectedImage;

    private LibVLC libVLC;
    private Uri currentVideoUri;


    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_editor);


        videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        Button buttonSelectImage = findViewById(R.id.buttonSelectImage);
        Button buttonSelectVideo = findViewById(R.id.buttonSelectVideo);
        Button buttonApplyFilter = findViewById(R.id.buttonApplyFilter);
        Button buttonAddText = findViewById(R.id.buttonAddText);
        Button buttonCombineMedia = findViewById(R.id.buttonCombineMedia);
        Button buttonAddAudio = findViewById(R.id.buttonAddAudio);

        buttonSelectImage.setOnClickListener(v -> openImageChooser());
        buttonSelectVideo.setOnClickListener(v -> openVideoChooser());
        buttonApplyFilter.setOnClickListener(v -> applyVideoFilter());
        buttonAddText.setOnClickListener(v -> addTextToImage());
        buttonCombineMedia.setOnClickListener(v -> mergeVideoClips());
        buttonAddAudio.setOnClickListener(v -> addAudio());
// This code is used toi call the various methods 

        ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<>();
        options.add("--no-plugins-cache");
        libVLC = new LibVLC(this, options);


    }

// To request permissions.
        private void requestPermissions() {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)          != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)       != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            }, REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);
        }
    }

        //To select Images
        private void openImageChooser() {
              Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
              intent.setType("image/*");
              startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }
          // To choose videos
          private void openVideoChooser() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("video/*");
                  startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Video"), PICK_VIDEO_REQUEST);
    }

        // The implementation to get videos.
         @Override
          protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
             super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
              if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                  if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST) {
                      try {
                     selectedImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                          imageView.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
                          imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                          videoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                      } catch (IOException e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                      }
                   } else if (requestCode == PICK_VIDEO_REQUEST) {
                        currentVideoUri = uri; // Save the URI
                       videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
                       MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
                     mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
                    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
                    videoView.start();
                     videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                     imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
               }
             }
          }

          //Code that allows you to apply a filter over the video.
          private void applyVideoFilter() {
                if (videoView.isShown()) {
                 if (currentVideoUri != null) {
                    String inputPath = getPathFromUri(currentVideoUri);
                      String outputPath = getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/filtered_video.mp4";
                      String[] com= {
                               "-i", inputPath, // Input file
                              "-vf", "hue=s=0", // Video filter: hue=s=0 applies grayscale
                              "-c:a", "copy", // Copy the audio as is
                               outputPath // Output file
                      };
                       executeFFmpegCommand(com);
                      } else {
                      Toast.makeText(this, "No video selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
                   } else {
                   Toast.makeText(this, "Select a video first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
          }



         // Code to get android permissions.
         @Override
         public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,          @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
              super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
               if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSIONS) {
                 if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                      // Permissions granted
                       applyVideoFilter();
                   } else {
                      // Permissions denied
                     Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
              }
           }
           // Code to get information about the video
          private String getPathFromUri(Uri uri) {
             // Convert URI to file path
               String[] projection = {MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA};
               Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
               if (cursor != null) {
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                 String path = cursor.getString(column_index);
                 cursor.close();
                 return path;
              }
               return null;
            }



             //Code to add text to image.
           private void addTextToImage() {
              if (videoView.isShown() && currentVideoUri != null) {
                String inputPath = getPathFromUri(currentVideoUri);
                if (inputPath == null) {
                     Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to get video path", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      return;
                 }

                   String outputPath = getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/text_added_video.mp4";
                 String text = "Sample Text"; // Or get input from user
                  String[] cmd = {
                          "-i", inputPath,
                          "-vf", "drawtext=text='" + text + "':x=10:y=10:fontsize=24:fontcolor=white",
                           "-c:a", "copy",
                            outputPath
                   };

                  executeFFmpegCommand(cmd);
                 } else {
                      Toast.makeText(this, "No video selected or video not visible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
           }

         // Code to merge video clips in one sequence.
          private void mergeVideoClips(List<Uri> videoUris) {
               StringBuilder concatFile = new StringBuilder();
              for (Uri uri : videoUris) {
                   concatFile.append("file '").append(getPathFromUri(uri)).append("'\n");
               }

              File fileList = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "concat_list.txt");
               try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileList)) {
                    fos.write(concatFile.toString().getBytes());
              } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
              }

              String outputPath = getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/merged_video.mp4";
               String[] cmd = {
                    "-f", "concat",
                    "-safe", "0",
                     "-i", fileList.getAbsolutePath(),
                      "-c", "copy",
                      outputPath
               };
               executeFFmpegCommand(cmd);
            }
          // Code to add Audio.
          private void addAudio(Uri videoUri, Uri audioUri) {
               String videoPath = getPathFromUri(videoUri);
               String audioPath = getPathFromUri(audioUri);
               String outputPath = getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/video_with_audio.mp4";

              String[] cmd = {
                     "-i", videoPath,
                      "-i", audioPath,
                      "-c:v", "copy",
                      "-c:a", "aac",
                      "-strict", "experimental",
                       outputPath
              };
              executeFFmpegCommand(cmd);
             }private void mergeVideoClips(List<Uri> videoUris) {
               StringBuilder concatFile = new StringBuilder();
                for (Uri uri : videoUris) {
                   concatFile.append("file '").append(getPathFromUri(uri)).append("'\n");
             }

               File fileList = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "concat_list.txt");
               try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileList)) {
                 fos.write(concatFile.toString().getBytes());
                 } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                }

                 String outputPath = getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/merged_video.mp4";
                 String[] cmd = {
                        "-f", "concat",
                        "-safe", "0",
                        "-i", fileList.getAbsolutePath(),
                        "-c", "copy",
                        outputPath
               };
               executeFFmpegCommand(cmd);
          }
         
           //Code to implement FFmpegKit implementation.
           private void executeFFmpegCommand(String[] cmd) {
                FFmpegKit.executeAsync(String.join(" ", cmd), (executionId, returnCode) -> {
                   if (returnCode.equals("0")) {
                      Toast.makeText(this, "Operation completed successfully",   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     // Handle post-processing if necessary
                   } else {
                       Toast.makeText(this, "Operation failed with return code: " + returnCode,       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
                });
            }
       }//(This is the java code )



I just do not know what to do. I can't seem to find anything useful online. The code below is my xml file for the video editor activity.



       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonSelectImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Select Image" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonSelectVideo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Select Video" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonApplyFilter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Apply Filter" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonAddText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add Text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonCombineMedia"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Combine Media" />

       <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonAddAudio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add Audio" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>


Th code below is my gradle app module.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.self_editor'
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.self_editor"
        minSdk 30
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        renderscriptTargetApi 18
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.5.31"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.31"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.2.4'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.zomato:android-libs:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptop:videofilters:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'org.videolan.android:libvlc-all:3.4.4'
    implementation 'com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-full:6.0-2'
}

